# Android "vspace" memory?

Tags: android, memory-management

I'd like to know a bit more about what is the vspace memory exactly. Running out of vspace memory when loading a lib for our android games often occurs as we tend to take as much ram as we can at the application startup. I haven't been able to find any information about it.

Here`s the error message I get:

```
11-11 16:00:57.057: ERROR/libEGL(946): load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so): Cannot load library: alloc_mem_region[847]: OOPS:    64 cannot map library 'libEGL_adreno200.so'. **no vspace available**.
```

What exactly is vspace memory?

Some links / info about android / linux memory model would be appreciated too!

Thanks!

Comment: `we tend to take as much ram as we can` sounds like you're doing wrong. This is an embedded device.

Comment: @falmarri it's done this way `cause we`re working with a porting layer and the big allocation is to render memory allocs the same accross platforms/devices (helps with fragmentation issues).

Comment: @commonsware that is my question really :) i'll update with the error msg i get

Answer (score 0):

vspace stands for "virtual [address] space".

In 32bit systems it is limited to 4GB, and often 1/4 of it is reserved for the OS.
Program binary and dynamically loaded libraries need to fit in the address space together with other mmapped files, address range used for memory allocations (heap) and threads' stacks.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of VSpace is just the Virtual Space in OS.

You meet this issue when you try to load a Shared Lib when start show a view ?

System provide the VSpace management .But in some custom-built Rom ,
VSpace sometimes may not be correctly set.I meet the issue in My program
Load a shared library(system's or mine) when I try to load a view which
need malloc a lot of memory for bitmap at the same time. I tried to ask 
the Rom system engineer if they has changed the VSpace setting , but their
answer is just nothing has been done. But I finally fix the issue.

If your issue is similar to mine .Follow the advice below :

1) Use smaller png or jpg for less memory use

2) Loading all the shared library before load a view.

Hope this help . Thanks