# How to free vspace in the Android emulator

Tags: android

Sometimes when I compile an app on my Android device I get the following errors:

```
E/HAL(2125): load: module=/system/lib/hw/gralloc.msm7k.so
E/HAL(2125): Cannot load library: alloc_mem_region[869]: OOPS:    93 cannot map library 'gralloc.msm7k.so'. no vspace available.
E/GraphicBufferMapper(2125): FATAL: can't find the gralloc module
```

How can I free up vspace to be able to compile the app again? I've already tried rebooting and turning off and on the phone but it didn't work.

The only thing I could find on Stackoverflow about this topic is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187696/android-vspace-memory) with no answer...

Comment: I am getting similar error, have you found any solution for this. For me it happens in android v 2.3.3 and not in 4.2.

Comment: @Droider no, I just know that it's not a coding problem

Comment: Try to examine Dev Tools app on simulator. There's a Terminal Emulator, maybe you will be able to achieve your goal with its help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under "additional emulator command line options," add this:

```
-partition-size 1024
```

then click on apply and run. If this fails, then add this instead:

```
memory -512
```

If all else fails:
Increase the AVD RAM and the max VM application heap size in VM options.
AVD Manager -> Virtual Devices -> Edit. It's probably set to 24, set it to 32 at first, then at 48 if it's still NOK.